# Why does delete[] result in heap corruption error?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I helped my friend with debugging a code, problematic part was something like that:

```
class MyClass {
    char * text;
public:
    MyClass(const char * c) {
        if (c != nullptr) {
            text = new char[strlen(c)];
            strcpy(text, c);
        }
        else
            text = nullptr;
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        delete[] text;
    }
};


int main() {
    MyClass foo("bar");
    return 0;
}
```

Of course problem is with `strlen(c)`, should be `strlen(c) + 1`. Anyway, what surprised me, why did that result in heap corruption error in the moment of calling delete[] in destructor? What caused it?

This error is thrown by debugger, my question is:
Why did this error popped up at the moment of freeing memory, not earlier?
It would be much easier to find any bugs in code this way.

@edit old c = nullptr -> text = nullptr
There was this bug I wrote accidentally, (sorry, I didn't notice, now it is what I meant). The thing is, it was forbidden to use strings in this task, so it had to be done C-way.

Comment: Most likely you violated the [rule of 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: @someprogrammerdude "*Of course problem is with strlen(c), should be strlen(c) + 1.*".

Comment: `c = nullptr` you probably mean `text = nullptr` there. ..

Comment: Your example is just a class definition; there are no `MyClass` objects created, so the destructor is not called. Post an MCVE please.

Comment: When you go out of bounds with the `strcpy` call you have *undefined behavior*. You can't really say what that will lead to, but most likely you overwrite some data used by the memory allocator leading to problems when you `delete[]`.

Comment: The `delete` in question is the cause of the message, not of the corruption. The memory manager checks before releasing memory that things are OK. When something isn't, it was usually caused a long time ago in a different part of the code.

Comment: Let's see... 1) using `char*` instead of `std::string`  2) not allocating enough memory for the null terminator  3) not handling the rule of three  4) assigning the constructor argument to null instead of the member variable. Did I miss any?

Comment: My advice: Understand and then fix the bug @NathanOliver mentioned.

Comment: It is just a part of code. I didn't see need to paste also copying operator, as in this case it doesn't matter, and makes code unnecessarily long.

Comment: ***Why did this error popped up at the moment of freeing memory, not earlier?*** From experience heap corruption is not necessarily detected in Visual Studio when the corruption occurs. You can't rely on detection happening just after the corruption. Although in this case the corruption was detected at the next possible time to detect the corruption. Visual Studio only checks when you allocate or free memory.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, this was exactly the answer I was looking for from the beginning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Why did this error popped up at the moment of freeing memory, not earlier?***

From experience heap corruption is not necessarily detected in Visual Studio when the corruption occurs. You can't rely on detection happening just after the corruption. Although in this case the corruption was detected at the next possible time to detect the corruption. Visual Studio only checks when you allocate or free memory.

Answer (score 3):

The heap corruption was **caused** by the call to `strcpy`, which wrote past the end of the allocated memory block. It was **detected** when the code called  `delete[]`.